# Will golang's GC free memory of object which only be referenced by a goroutine?

Tags: go

```
m := map[string]*Object {
    "a": obj
}
go func(obj *Object) {
    obj.Do()
}(m["a"])

delete(m, "a")
```

will GC free memory of `obj` when `obj.Do()` has not finished?

Comment: No, it will not free the memory of any block of memory reachable from any goroutine.

Comment: It would be a pretty awful garbage collector if it collected memory that's still in use.

Comment: Why do you ask? What on earth makes you think the garbage collector is buggy?

Comment: I think he may have been concerned about the "obj" stored in the map, and when exactly the argument to the goroutine start function is evaluated, m["a"].  If that expression were not evaluated right away then it would be possible that obj was deleted from the map and that it was potentially even gc'ed before being passed to the anonymous function in the new goroutine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will evaluate

```
m["a"]
```

which will give the pointer obj, then obj will be placed on a new stack for the goroutine, and then the goroutine will be started with that stack, and then obj will be removed from the map in the original goroutine.  At that point the new goroutine stack will have a pointer to obj, and so obj will not be gc'ed for that reason until the 2nd goroutine completes execution.